# How to prove or disprove surjectivity of a complex function?

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers, proof-writing

I have the following complex function:

$f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ where $f(z)=z^2+2z+3$

This function is trivially not injective since it's not injective in the real subsets.

Now, I am very inclined to think that this function is surjective and I am trying to prove it.

The way I am trying to do it the typical, assume $z_0=f(z)$ for some $z\in \mathbb{C}$ show that this equation always has a solution.

Since these are complex numbers we want the real part to equal the real part and the imaginary part to equal the imaginary part in both sides of the equation. However, trying to solve the above system of 2 nonlinear equations results in some very long expressions and I am having trouble with the algebra.

I want to know if there is a simpler way to show surjectivity or if I am wrong and this function is not surjective.

Comment: do you know discriminants?

Comment: @TsemoAristide I fail to see how that is relevant

Comment: $z_0=f(z)$ is a quadratic equation.

Comment: I think the quadratic formula will work for you.

Comment: @TsemoAristide over the complex numbers.

Comment: $f(z)-z_0$ is a quadratic polynomial with complex coefficients, so it has at least one complex root by the FTA ([Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra)).

Comment: @dxiv you don't need FTA. that's overkill

Comment: @KennyLau That depends on the context. If you *know* the FTA then it's an overkill to *not* use it.

Comment: And if I don't know the FTA (officially)? 

I understand that you are saying use the quadratic formula, and then you'll find at least one root, however, this involves taking the root of a complex number, and I am not sure if you can always do that?

Comment: @Makogan You can write $\,f(z)=z_0 \iff (z+1)^2=z_0-2\,$. Let $z+1=x + iy$ then solve the *real* system $x^2-y^2 = a\,$, $2xy=b$ where $a=\operatorname{Re}(z_0)-2, b=\operatorname{Im}(z_0)\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seek a zero of $$f(z)-z_0= (z+1)^2+(2-z_0)$$
To find a zero of this, you need to solve $$(z+1)^2=z_0-2$$
So, suppose that $z_0-2$ is an arbitrary complex number.  Can you find a square root, i.e. $y\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $y^2=z_0-2$?  If so, then $y=z+1$, so you seek $z=y-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof that works for rational functions which I though it might be worth mentioning.

The rational functions are the complex analytic maps $\mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^1$, by compactness the image is closed, by the open mapping theorem the image is open, so it must be surjective by connectedness. (this in particular proves fundamental theorem of algebra)

For an elementary proof for this particular case see vadim123's answer.